# Edge over ngon not working as expected, face not selectable

Tags: modeling, edges

I have this ngon which I am trying to turn into a quad, I added an edge split on the side (it wouldn't go all, over the top face) and then I added a vertex on the middle edge and connected to the new edge loop, however first of all:

1. I got a weird dotted line on my mirror
2. If I select the face it acts as if the line doesn't exist, looks like 2 faces are selected but it is actually one face with an ignored edge in the middle

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: If you want to split a face by joining two vertices, use 'J' (Join) NOT 'F' (Fill). F will create a floating edge between the vertices but it will not split the face.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes that's it! Can you post it as the answer please as it answers my question?

Comment: Answer now posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to split a face by joining two vertices, hit <kbd>J</kbd> (Join) not <kbd>F</kbd> (Fill).
The images below demonstrate what happens when you use each method to join opposing vertices on a cube:

1> Using <kbd>F</kbd> (Fill):

[image]

This has created an edge between the vertices but it has **not** split the face:

[image]

You can demonstrate this by subdividing the line, grabbing the centre vertex created, and moving it up:

[image]

The edge is only connected to the face at the original vertices.

2. Using <kbd>J</kbd> (Join)

[image]

The result looks the same, but the face is actually split by the edge as you can see by selecting the triangular faces independently:

[image]

Comment: Ha  I haven't been use it in my 20 year experience, thanks for the answer. In this case I used a knife tool I guess ...

Comment: Just something else to remember! :^)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have to delete this face and connect edges by yourself. Because I also often encounter such a problem, but it's usually enough for me to simply delete the face and connect everything on my own

Answer (score -1):

If I were in this situation, I would delete the face that cause problem, and also delete the edge above the face. and then I would make one more edge loope not to make n gon.

Answer (score -2):

you should remove the face and use a knife to get the middle line back