# Problem using FKey in v 3.6

Tags: vertices

In 2.8 I could connect two vertices using the F Key.  This doesn't work in 3.6.  How is this accomplished in 3.6?  I have the same add-ons as in 2.8.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It certainly does work in Blender 3.6! See my answer in this recent posting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296676/edge-over-ngon-not-working-as-expected-face-not-selectable/296690#296690

Comment: Would you mind showing at least one screenshot of the mesh and which vertices you want to connect there? Because F definitely works in 3.6.0

Comment: It turned out that my  "problem" was located above my shoulders.  There was a stupid modeling error.  Version 3.6 is fine.  Thank you for your help.