# How do I merge an edge onto a face to make a face cut?

Tags: faces, edges

I have made these edges and they're connected to the surrounding edges, but it doesn't seem to be linked to the faces directly as it doesn't consider the face split in two. How would I go about merging or snapping the edge onto the face to make the face cut? [image] [image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296676/edge-over-ngon-not-working-as-expected-face-not-selectable/296690#296690

Comment: Ah nice that seems to have done the trick for me, thank you! Would you also know if there happens to be a menu options to do it too as well as an option to do the opposite (splitting the edge from the face)?

Comment: Fill and Join are both on the Vertex menu. Fill is called 'New Edge/Face from Vertices' and Join is 'Connect Vertex Path' so you can probably see why I use hotkeys! I'm not sure why you would want to do the oposite to be honest and I doubt there's an option to do that although you could select the edge and press 'P' to seperate it into a new object. You'd still need to use Ctrl-X to dissolve the original edge though.

Comment: It's mainly out of curiosity for potential future reference. Thank you for the answers!